# JavaScript; Getting the content of the file into array chunks

Tags: javascript, arrays, chunks

I am working on the Google Drive API to get a document from the google drive, and then I’m trying to get the document’s contents into chunks of blocks so I can encrypt block-by-block. Can you help me figure out a way of achieving that? This is what I have tried.

```
function getDocumentContents() {
    var accessToken = user.getAuthResponse().access_token;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', 'https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/' + fileId
            + '?alt=media');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + accessToken);
    xhr.onload = function() {
        modelContent = xhr.responseText;
        extractKey(xhr.responseText);
    };
    xhr.onerror = function() {
        alert('error');
    };
    xhr.send();
    var chunkSize=512*512;
    var fileSize=file.size;
    var chunks=Math.ceil(xhr.size/chunkSize,chunkSize);
    var chunk=0;
    console.log('chunks...',chunks);
    while( chunk <= chunks)
        var offset=chunk*chunkSize;
        console.log('current chunk..', chunk);
        chunk.send();
        console.log('offset',offset);
        console.log(xhr.slice(offset,offset+chunkSize));
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Explain the difference? _I am using JavaScript to get the contents of a file into chunks of arrays_ vs. _I need some help getting the contents of the documents into chunks and storing them into arrays_

Comment: can you show what have you tried already?

Comment: @A.KHussain - OK then. Good luck.

Comment: @KarenGrigoryan I have edited and posted

Comment: Please take some time to clarify your problem. Here it is really unclear for us who just come here as to - What is the broad goal you are trying to achieve? - What limitations made you come to this attempt? - What is the real problem you are facing?. Now, there are things in your code block that will make it obviously fail. e.g `xhr` being an XMLHttpRequest object, it doesn't have a `size` property nor a `slice` method, `chunk` being a number primitive, it doesn't have a `send` method etc. But once again, I think you should try to read your question with the eyes of a complete stranger first.

Comment: @Kaiido I have now written it with changes, sorry for the unclear note.

Comment: @Kaiido If I have to get the contents of the document , is there an object that I can use? That would get me the content from the document, and then using that object , can I get the data into chunks?

Comment: What are these documents? Binary files? If so, request them as Blob or ArrayBuffer from your xhr request and then simply slice them. But here I am still really unclear as to what is after `xhr.send()`. I guess/hope this is actually part of the `extractKey` function, but `chunk.send()` makes no sense to me.

Comment: @Kaiido These are text documents that are present on the Google Drive, I was just given a project where I need to encrypt documents while people edit their contents in parallel on Google Docs, we're trying to secure it, by dividing the contents into blocks, then encrypting, if a change is made by the user at his end, an update to one of the block would lead to an event that would send the block index and the block thats updated